# WCF SecurityException

Tags: wcf, iis-6

I am trying to host a WCF service in IIS 6.0 on server 2003.  And when I
browse to the server I get the following error.

SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
'System.Net.DnsPermission

Is this related to the permissions granted to the user account the app
pool is running under or some other problem, and how do I fix this.

Comment: I think we're going to need more information.  Is that the entire error message?  Have you tried googling?  Lastly, go grab a copy of "Programming WCF Services" and see if there's anything helpful in there.  :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to the settings for local Intranet. I am assuming that you are browsing from your PC to the server. Try this:

- Connect to the server via Remote desktop (or just use the server console), then browse the service and see if you get the same error.

If you do not get an error:

- On your PC add the address of the server to local intranett, then try and browse the service again.

Good luck

Shiraz

Comment: I was actually browsing to the service from a local browser on the windows 2003 server via Remote Desktop already, not from my PC.  So it appears to be a server error of some sort and not related to the client browsing to the service.

Comment: When you browse does it say loacl Intranett in the bottom right hand corner of the screen?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the replies.

Yes that was the entire error message Terry.  It didn't appear to be a WCF issue but a security configuration problem on the web server that wasn't allowing DNS Permission as required by WCF.

The problem was resolved by uninstalling SharePoint services on that server where the WCF service was being hosted.  Not sure still, why SharePoint would change the security permissions.